# Facebook returns expired access token

Tags: android, facebook

i,m trying to get access token from facebbok via android phone but provider returns token expired 2 months ago. Do You know what's wrong?

Comment: show us the way you access the token and requesting the authorization

Comment: I am using facebook sdk 3.7, and method session.getAccessToken() after  facebookLoginButton click

Comment: IF the session is expired proceed with the authorization flow

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe said, it's not possible to automatically extend the validity of the tokens (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending).

Citation.

"Even the long-lived access token will eventually expire. At any point, you can generate a new long-lived token by sending the person back to the login flow used by your web app"

I'd recommend that you try to catch the error codes (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#errors) which will probably be error code 190 and error subcode 463 from the JSON error message and for example send the specific user an email with an invitation to revisit your app...